# Elegant English term for performing a "fausse manoeuvre"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a descriptive, elegant English term or phrase for *fausse manoeuvre*, which is when a technical operator (a human) performs a "bad" operation or sequence of actions.

For example, "The electrician performed a *fausse manoeuvre* when he rewired the machine, leading to a short circuit."

I am leaning towards "maloperation", but that often describes an automatic component malfunctioning rather than human error. What would be the best English term?

Comment: Does it need to be a *technical* operator who "performs a bad operation or sequence of actions"?

Comment: What does "bad" operation mean? Are we talking a typo/miskeying or sabotage?

Comment: I suppose 'pig's ear' and 'dog's breakfast' don't come in the 'elegant' style class.

Comment: In conversational (primarily, "non-technical") contexts, the basic translation *[He made a] **wrong move*** would normally be fine. In Technical contexts, maybe *[The user did / performed / carried out an] **incorrect operation***.

Comment: fausse manoeuvre is often used to refer to driving some kind of  **vehicle**. A fausse manoeuvre can be hitting the gas instead of the brake. So, it might not even appear in the translation because you would say: I stepped on the gas instead of the brake.

Comment: @Joachim, yes. For example, "The technical operator resolved a problem caused when the programmer used the wrong Python operator to denote the mathematical operator."

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered 'mishandle'?

> Manage or deal with (something) wrongly or ineffectively. <sup>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mishandle)</sup>

The word implies both human manipulation and "bad" operation.

As a noun '*mishandling*' can work, but '*misstep*' might be more elegant:

> A clumsy or badly judged step. <sup>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/misstep)</sup>

(Here the emphasis has migrated to the feet of the human :)

The literal translation — '*(to make) a false move*' — is clear as well, though.

Comment: One would not say, in a professional context, "the electrician mishandled the repair" or "the electrician performed a misstep when rewiring the machine". When reporting to laypeople this might translate what happened, but it is not appropriate among professionals.

Comment: @herman That the word was to be used in a 'professional context' has not been established.